# How to wait till the response comes from the $http request and assign value in $scope variable in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

this is the situation :

```
$scope.signupNow = function () {
  retrieveData();
  console.log($scope.userid);
}

function retrieveData(){
    // ** some http request **
    $scope.userid = id; 
}
```

now http request take some time to execute and there is no value in "$scope.userid" because it's just print after calling the function.

Can you please suggest that How to wait till the response comes????

Comment: Write down your code in callback functions. It's happening due to `async` behave of AJAX. Put your code in `.then(function () {` -- code -- `})`

Comment: Did you even read the $http documentation on the Angular website? It pretty clearly describes the use of promises (you might want to do some reading on that subject).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok if u want to wait until http response then u can use a callback function

```
$scope.signupNow = function () {

    retrieveData(function(){

        console.log($scope.userid);
    });   
}

function retrieveData(callback){
    // ** some http request **
    $scope.userid = id; 
    callback();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$scope.signupNow = function () {

  retrieveData().then(funtion(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
    // do here what you need
  });
}

function retrieveData(){
  return $http.get('url');
}
```

Comment: Sorry mate, getting error with the above which is "retrieveData() is undefined"

Comment: Named functions are hoisted to the top of the file at runtime in javascript, so it should be defined.

Answer (score 0):

Use angularJs promise -

```
$scope.signupNow = function () {
   var promise  = retrieveData();
   promise.then(function(success) {
     console.log($scope.userid);
   }, function(reason) {
     alert('Failed: ' + reason);
   });

 }


function retrieveData(){
 var deferred = $q.defer();
 (your http request).then(){
   $scope.userid = id;
   deferred.resolve('success');
  }
  return deferred .promise;
}
```